# JasperReports Server: How to set Default value for Input Control

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

[image]

In JasperReports Server input controls default value showing like this "---" but i want default value is "All" and that **input controls must be not mandatory**.

I am getting details for Database.

How to set Default value?

Answer (score 0):

You have to handle the default value in your query. Can you post the query for the input control.

Comment: This is my query 


SELECT code, txt, 2 as ID FROM tablename
UNION
Select 'All','All',1 as ID
ORDER BY ID Asc,itmtxt ASC

Comment: Modify your query to `select * from (Select 'All','All',0 as ID UNION  SELECT code, txt, 1 as ID FROM tablename) ORDER BY ID Asc,itmtxt ASC`. Hope this should solve your issue. Also Check mandatory for that input control

Comment: Preview Query also working for me if checked as mandatory for that input control. I want input control as non mandatory and Default value as 'All'

Answer (score 0):

If your intention is to default to selecting all the values available (in your input control) turn off the "always prompt" checkbox in the Controls & Resources when you edit the settings for your report.

If this is not un-checked the effect is that the report runs but does not display any data until you have applied (i.e. clicked the Apply button) the filter selection.

How can I be professional, Jasper studio/jasper reports is "awkward".